# How to install Y&Y

Tags: installing, windows, software

I was downloaded Y&Y source code from CTAN, but I don't know how to install it. can anybody help me.

I am using windows 7. I have installed GCC also

Comment: Why do you want to install Y&Y instead of a current tex system?

Comment: The YandY distribution on CTAN is dated 2014, but only because at that time the package has been made publicly available. Its development stopped much earlier: for instance it doesn't support `pdftex`. It's possibly interesting as *archaeoware*, not for actual document production.

Comment: @egreg Well, the poster is still using Win7, so maybe he likes running outdated software. :-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: https://www.tug.org/yandy/